Не убирается outline или border у input:focus
верстаю сейчас на Tailwind, и при фокусе на инпуте у него бордер синий, я хочу его убрать, пишу в css input:focus { outline: none !important; border: none !important; }
А он все равно не убирается


Одно из двух: либо там инлайн-стили перебивают ваше правило, либо стилизуется не сам инпут, а его обёртка.

А как же стилизуется не сам инпут? Я же пишу input:focus {})

Ну, это Вы пишете, а у фреймворка, который Вы используете, своё мнение на этот счёт ;-)

В официальном мануале написано что нужно добавить к input focus:outline-none
выйдет примерно вот так


<input type="email" name="email" class="focus:outline-none" placeholder="you@example.com" />



